# Summoning Encoder[OneAnd[NonEmptyList, Int]]?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, circe

Given:

```
@ import $ivy.`io.circe::circe-core:0.9.3` 
import $ivy.$                           

@ import $ivy.`io.circe::circe-generic:0.9.3` 
import $ivy.$                              

@ import cats._, cats.data._, io.circe._, io.circe.Encoder._, io.circe.Decoder._ 
import cats._, cats.data._, io.circe._, io.circe.Encoder._, io.circe.Decoder._

@ val x: OneAnd[NonEmptyList, Int] = OneAnd(1, NonEmptyList(2, Nil)) 
x: OneAnd[NonEmptyList, Int] = OneAnd(1, NonEmptyList(2, List()))

@ import io.circe.syntax._ 
import io.circe.syntax._

@ x.asJson 
cmd5.sc:1: could not find implicit value for parameter encoder: io.circe.Encoder[cats.data.OneAnd[cats.data.NonEmptyList,Int]]
val res5 = x.asJson
             ^
Compilation Failed
```

Perhaps I'm missing an `import` in order to use https://github.com/circe/circe/blob/58107ee7c82769f56e5cd932c21493dfe239b6d6/modules/core/shared/src/main/scala/io/circe/Encoder.scala#L343-L350's `Encoder#encodeOneAnd`?

Please let me know how to resolve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Adding the import

```
import io.circe.generic.auto._
```

solved it for me. Hope this helps.